# Is there any (convenient) way of retrieving current iteration # inside C++11 "foreach" statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering whether it is possible to somehow extract current iteration number from c++11 foreach statement.

In code like this:

```
for(auto &i: vect)
    if(i == 0) zero_value_index = /* here I want my index */;
```

I can't find another way around, but using old-fashioned `for` with `int i` to easily obtain my index.

Ideas?

Comment: `auto it = std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 0);`

Comment: Just use regular for-loop with index.

Comment: There isn't anything that isn't ugly enough to make it preferable to use an index- or iterator-based loop, or a standard library algorithm.

Comment: What's wrong with a regular `for` statement? Just because C++11 added the range based `for` doesn't mean you need to use it everywhere.

Comment: @dribeas: That snippet is not only slow on most containers, on containers that allow duplication, it's outright **wrong**.  Oh, you weren't suggesting it for the general case.  Well, it still gives a difference answer when duplicates are present.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I need specific index for comparison between two vectors and as Ben mentioned - it'd be wrong in most cases.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What is *slow* in `std::find`? It was a wild guess that he is only interested in finding --i.e. the rest of the body being empty. But I am surprised on the claim of that being *slow*

Comment: @Praetorian: regular for statement gives you the current iterator, not the iteration number.  Unless you're writing code that is very unfriendly to containers other than `vector` and `array`.

Comment: @Pearley: `auto index = std::distance(it,vect.begin());`

Comment: @dribeas: I misinterpreted your suggestion as: `for(auto& el : vect)
    index = find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), el);`

Comment: @dribeas: `std::distance` only works efficiently on random-access containers.

Comment: Yes, this is (again guess) a vector. Otherwise the alternative of *old-fashioned `for` with `int i`* would be out of question :)

Comment: @BenVoigt Not if you iterate over `[0, vector::size())` instead of using iterators. Agreed that that isn't the best option for all containers, but, judging from the variable names, OP is dealing with a `vector`.

Comment: @Praetorian: The example code uses a vector, probably.  But the title and question are generic to iteration of any container type.  So I think it's good to have an answer that's good for any container type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could, I don't know, **count the iterations**:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto& el : container) {
    if (el == 0) zero_value_index = i;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not convenient nor elegant, when you have ready to use non-rangebased for's counter.

Comment: @Pearley: If you're using a counter to iterate an abstracted container, you're doing it wrong.  That's what iterators are for.  And conversion between iterator and index is only trivial for random-access containers.

Comment: @Pearley: To be clear, what I'm saying is non-rangebased for looks like `for( auto it = begin(container), end = end(container); it != end; ++it )` and you still don't have the index readily available.  You can use `i = it - begin;`, but only for random-access containers.

Comment: I don't see why this would be considered inconvenient.  As for elegance: if you need the index, then you need the index (assuming that you really need the index) - elegance be damned.

Comment: I'm newb, forgive me neglecting abstracted containers ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you follow [Ben Voigt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23437029/3033711), the short answer is no.

Since you have a `vector`, there's nothing wrong with an old fashioned for-loop. Anything else will be needlessly complicated.

```
typedef std::vector <int>::size_type size_type ;
for(size_type i = 0; i < vect.size (); ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

This can work for other containers, such as strings, but not much else:

```
template <class Container>
void DoStuff (Container &container)
{
    typedef Container::size_type size_type ;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < container.size (); ++i) {
        //...       
    }
}
```

Or you could have something ugly like this:

```
template <class Container>
struct StoreIndex
{
    typedef typename Container::size_type size_type ;
    typedef typename Container::value_type value_type ;

    StoreIndex (Container &container) : container (container), index (0)
    {
    }

    size_type index ;
    Container &container ;

    value_type operator () () {
        if (container [index] == 0) {
            return index++ ;
        }

        else {
            return container [index++] ;
        }
    }
};
```

And then do:

```
std::generate (std::begin (v), std::end (v), StoreIndex <std::vector <int> > (v)) ;
```

Of course, this is just as limited as the other two methods (think `std::map`, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I had another think about this overnight. The answer is yes. You can find the index without counting.
This is because of the following two rules:

- data in a std::vector is guaranteed to be contiguous.
- subtracting two pointers yields a distance in "object sizes", not bytes.

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> rhyme = { "humpty", "dumpty", "sat", "on", "a", "wall" };


int main()
{
    for(const auto& s : rhyme) {
        if (s == "on") {
            const size_t index = &s - rhyme.data(); // index computed here
            cout << "found at index " << index << endl;
        }    
    }

   return 0;
}
```